# Understanding Monad Transformer Type Signatures

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm currently tackling monad transformers and trying to really understand the type signatures, and I'm having some confusion. Let's use the following stack for discussion:

```
newtype Stack s m a = Stack { runStack :: ReaderT s (StateT s IO) a }
```

I'm trying to go through layer by layer and write the unwrapped type signatures but getting stuck:

```
newtype Stack s m a = Stack { 
    runStack :: ReaderT s         (StateT s IO)       a }
--              ReaderT s                  m          a
--                      s ->               m          a
--                      s ->         (StateT s IO)    a
--                            StateT  s     m         a
--                      s ->         (s -> IO (a, s)) a
```

That just doesn't look like a valid return type signature on the last line, we have essentially a function that takes an s and returns a function shoved up against an `a`?

I *get* that the inner function evaluates to a Monad eventually, and that's why it's the `m` in `ReaderT r m a`, but it's bending my brain.

Could anyone offer any insight, have I correceclty analyzed the types and I just have to accept that `s -> (s -> IO (a, s)) a` is indeed valid?

Thank you

Comment: We have `newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }`. That being so, `(StateT s IO)    a` boils down to `s -> IO (a,s)`, and there is no dangling `a`.

Comment: @duplode what about the `a` that ReaderT returns? `newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }`.  Because `IO (a,s)` has the `a` in the tuple it's been removed from far right like I have it above?

Comment: "what about the `a` that ReaderT returns?" -- That's the `a` in `(StateT s IO) a`. Note that `ReaderT` doesn't return an `a` per se, but rather an `m a`.

Comment: @duplode :mind-blown: that makes total sense now, wow thanks so much for clearing that up for me!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stack you wrote is a little odd because it's parametrized by `m` on the left but specialized to `IO` on the right, so let's look at the fully `m`-parametrized variant:

```
newtype Stack s m a = Stack { runStack :: ReaderT s (StateT s m) a }
```

Now `runStack` here is just a field name, so we can drop it and write the equivalent `newtype` definition:

```
newtype Stack s m a = Stack (ReaderT s (StateT s m) a)
```

We also have the following library newtype definitions, skipping the field names.  I've also used fresh variables so we don't do something stupid like confuse two `a`s in different scope while expanding:

```
newtype ReaderT r1 m1 a1 = ReaderT (r1 -> m1 a1)
newtype StateT s2 m2 a2 = StateT (s2 -> m2 (a2, s2))
```

Of course, if we're only interested in the type up to isomorphism, then the newtype wrappers don't matter, so just rewrite these as type aliases:

```
type Stack s m a = ReaderT s (StateT s m) a
type ReaderT r1 m1 a1 = r1 -> m1 a1
type StateT s2 m2 a2 = s2 -> m2 (a2, s2)
```

Now, it's easy to expand the `Stack` type:

```
Stack s m a
= ReaderT s (StateT s m) a
-- expand ReaderT with r1=s, m1=StateT s m, a1=a
= s -> (StateT s m) a
= s -> StateT s m a
-- expand StateT with s2=s m2=m a2=a
= s -> (s -> m (a, s))
= s -> s -> m (a, s)
```

As @duplode noted, there's no extra `a` here.

Intuitively this `Stack` reads from an `s` (first argument) takes an initial state of type `s` (second argument), and returns a monadic action in `m` (e.g., `IO`) that can return a value of type `a` and an updated state of type `s`.

Comment: You're answer was very helpful, I really appreciate it, thanks!